# UICollectionView: get profile pictures from Instagram instead of recent media pictures to display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, instagram, nsurlsession

I am a newbie iOS learner.  Couldn't find answer to following question after searching for a while.  Hence, here it is.

Building on a first app that displays recent pictures from a user's instagram feed, I am trying to display pictures from the follows of that users instead.

To call recent pictures from the Instagram feed, which worked well, I had created the following method "imageForPhoto"

```
+ (void)imageForPhoto:(NSDictionary *)photo size:(NSString *)size completion:(void(^)(UIImage *image))completion {
if (photo == nil || size == nil || completion == nil) {
    return;
}

NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@-%@", photo[@"id"], size];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:photo[@"images"][size][@"url"]];
[self downloadURL:url key:key completion:completion];
```

}

Therefore, I first modified my code to get the data related to the "follows" in my PhotosViewController instead of recent media pictures ( v1/users/3/follows ):

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/follows?count=99&access_token=%@", self.accessToken];
```

Then, I created a new method that I called friendAvatarForPhoto to get the follows profile pictures from a photo NSDictionary that is passed in as the only method parameter.  I placed this method in my PhotoController class:

```
+ (void)friendAvatarForPhoto:(NSDictionary *)photo completion:(void(^)(UIImage *image))completion {
if (photo == nil || completion == nil) {
    return;
}

NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"avatar-%@", photo[@"user"][@"id"]];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:photo[@"profile_picture"]];
[self downloadURL:url key:key completion:completion];
```

}

It seems to work.  I have manually checked that the pictures that are rendered on my UICollectionView are actually coming from the "profile_picture" key of the responseDictionary I get back from Instagram.

Here is the structure of this dictionary: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldjqupadqg0j3nq/friends_response_dictionary.png

Specifically, as you can see, I modified both the key and the url:

```
NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"avatar-%@", photo[@"user"][@"id"]];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:photo[@"profile_picture"]];
```

but I am not really understanding what I need to initial the *key string with...  I kept "avatar" for example but why should I?  I am pretty sure it's wrong although the result seems to be fine from what is returned on my UICollectionView.

What should I initiate this string with instead?
What is the function of this key in the overall NSURLSession process?

I'd love to better understand the overall process and better connect the dots with Instagram's API so I can query the right key and be sure I am getting what I am looking for.  In a reliable way, not an intuitive one as I have just done app-arently.

Any help from experienced developers in the community would be welcome, I've just started to explore iOS dev a few weeks ago based on rusty C skills from a long time back.

Thank you!
:) Arsene

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are actually trying to do here. You said you want to get the image URLs of each user's profile photo. You seem to have that part done as it is just the "profile_picture" key in each user dictionary. so what else are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Dima:  Thanks for getting back to me.  Two things: 1) Understand what is the function of the key in: `NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"avatar-%@", photo[@"user"][@"id"]];`  I have changed the parameters and it didn't have any impact on the pictures being returned from Instagram.  I think I just don't understand the fonction of this pointer. 2) I logged in with another user account, got the same pictures...  Why?  I coded: `/users/3/follows?count=99&access_token=%@", self.accessToken];` which should return different pictures (the "follows" pictures) for each account. Thanks

Comment: Figured out answers to both questions:1) The key is a local string to uniquely identify the pictures stored on ache on the iphone's hard drive 2) the correct url from the instagram api is: [link] (https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?count=99&access_token=%@", self.accessToken];)  Thanks anyway! :)